# is openSips alone acts as a Media-server?

Tags: sip

I have a SIP Server running OpenSIPs

```
   Installed With the Latest Version
   Also Seen Media Proxy In their Modules
```

As i have Two Ip-phones with me.I have started OpenSIPs server

I want to make call between These Two Ip-Phones.Is it Possible with the OpenSIPs to make a call without any Media Server like Asterisk

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible - only if both devices are on the same LAN and using the same codec, then yes.

By default, opensips handles call setup, and the media goes between the devices, but this only works in the above case.

If you are using a different codec, or one or both devices are behind NAT, then you need a media bridge, like rtpproxy or rtpengine. This can be installed to the same server as opensisps - but opensips cannot handle media by default, like Asterisk.